# OpenSSL with C++

Tags: c++, openssl

У меня есть собранная библиотека OpenSSL, но мне оттуда нужен один алгоритм, правильно ли я понимаю, что если я возьму исходники и выдерну оттуда все нужные функции(и сопутствующие функции) и структуры в свой проект оно соберется? или нет

Comment: Во-первых, ну попробуйте и посмотрите, соберётся или нет. Во-вторых, имейте в виду, что при использовании кода openssl вы должны будете соблюдать лицензию openssl

Comment: Наверняка соберется, если правильно определите, что выдергивать. Но зачем? Неужели openssl такой жирный? Я бы лучше посмотрел в сторону автоматизации: были какие-то флаги линковщика для удаления неиспользуемого кода.

Comment: Ну 3мб итоговая сборка, хотелось поменьше

Comment: Вы линкуетесь статически? При статической линковке как раз "выдёргиваются" только те символы, которые нужны. Попробуйте `-l:libcrypto.a`, изменится ли размер бинарника

Comment: да, статически, просто помимо самого openssl VS требует еще и библиотеку для работы с  сокетами
(Ws2_32.lib)

Comment: Пишите `@username` когда отвечаете, а то уведомления не приходят.

Comment: Гугл подсказывает флаг линковщика `/OPT:REF` для убирания неиспользуемых функций.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  да, флаг помог, размер с 3мб уменьшился до 1.8мб